# Security vulnerabilities for Sheetjs

Tags: sheetjs

We are using Sheetjs in Salesforce, and are planning to get the pro version. Before using this library in production I just wanted to know if there are any security vulnerabilities for this library in the past. And is there any potential data threat as a result of using this library?

I tried searching on the web for any vulnerabilities reported in the past, but did not get proper information i needed. Could someone tell me if you've faced any potential data issues/security issues of using this library with Salesforce LWC components. Does Salesforce scans/checks the libraries we use in the components while deploying?

Answer (score 0):

According to [SNYK Advisor](https://snyk.io/advisor/npm-package/sheetjs), there are no known vulnerabilities.

And users are restricted to uploading only [valid files](https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/miscellany/formats). But I'm curious to know whether a user could import an excel with harmful macros or not. I can't find much about that.